# Are there illegal characters for creating QRCode with ZXing?

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I tried to create a QR Barcode generator using ZXing. I wanted to encode a mecode object in the QR Code: http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/developer/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html

I have this code

```
        bitMatrix = writer.encode(mecard, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);
        BufferedImage img = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream b64 = new Base64.OutputStream(os);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", b64);
        String result = os.toString("UTF-8");
```

Which generates the correct output when creating text and urls. But when I try to encode `"MECARD:N:Doe,John;TEL:(+32) 472 65 58 20;TEL:(+32) 2 577 50 68;EMAIL:John@iCompany.com;;"`
It gives an Invalid Base64 String. Are there some illegal characters that the encoder can't handle?

Comment: If the error is in base 64 encoding, then it occurs at the point you are writing image data as Base 64 data (why?), which is after using zxing and so nothing to do with it. Why do you think it has anything to do with the encoded data?

Comment: I actually found the problem. But couldn't answer yet myself. The MECARD spec does not allow multiple TEL parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the MECARD spec. MECARD Only allows one TEL part. I wanted to use two. That's it